# Savepoint in database

Tags: database, transactions

I am researching on transaction savepoint in databases but what I am not getting is what exactly is the information which is saved during savepoint. It has to be little bulky since it will be used to rollback the transaction to the savepoint and restart from there. please provide some link or info to get detailed understanding. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a regular backups...

Make sure that you can restore what you need - specific database, table etc.

Comment: Thanks! but my question is less with the relations perspective more towards processing side of a transaction. Lets say I save Program counter PC, cache snapshot, lock manager snapshot, log is already there getting stored lets say using WAL, what more needs to be saved?